# tables and matrices are misaligned in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

When I create data frames and matrices, the values are not neatly aligned by their columns.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Probably something is off in my R formats, but can't figure out which one.

[image: misaligned data frame example]

Comment: This is default way of displaying dataframes. If you want something neat, lok for `formattable`

Comment: @Hardikgupta No, it's not. Columns are neatly aligned in my R console.

Comment: Please provide your GUI preferences settings.

Comment: what do you mean by GUI preference settings? could you be more specific? I'm a real noob at R

Comment: You are using a variable-width font, so that for example `i` takes up less space than `m`. Here's ten `i` and ten `m` n the default font: iiiiiiiiiimmmmmmmmmm`  and ten in the "code" font: `iiiiiiiiiimmmmmmmmmm`. Set your console font to something with fixed letter space, like Courier.

Comment: Almost every software has preferences or options. Find these for R GUI (from the menu) and post a screenshot.